# R function values without default that are ignored

Tags: r, function

We have a function that requires multiple arguments without default values for any of them. However, even if some of them are not specified, the function returns a value, if these parameters are only used to subset a matrix (and possibly other types). We are puzzled why this is the case - can anybody help?

Specifically, why does the following code not return an error, but sums over the entire matrix and ignores `j`:

```
foo <- function(mat, j){
  v <- sum(mat[,j])
  v
}

foo(mat = matrix(1:4,3,4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the argument is never evaluated.

```
foo <- function(x)
    bar(x)

bar <- function(y)
    missing(y)

foo()
#[1] TRUE
foo(43)
#[1] FALSE
```

The inner function, in your case `[`, which has formal arguments `i, j, ..., drop = FALSE`, most likely checks whether the argument `j` is missing, and if it is missing it doesn't try to evaluate it.

Comment: So when `R` can't find a value for `j` in its environment, it will just ignore that `j` was supposed to indicate a column (row)? Is this always the case when indexing an object?

Comment: No, when R evaluates `j` and `j` is not found in the current or in the parent environments, it raises an error. In this case there's no error because `j` is not evaluated. In R arguments are evaluated in the function environment when (if) they're needed, and some special functions like `missing()` don't evaluate their arguments at all.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/function-argument-lists-and-missing/), optional arguments without defaults are missing from the inside of the function. Testing for it returns `TRUE`.

```
foo <- function(mat, j){
   v <- sum(mat[,j]); print(missing(j))
   v
}
foo(mat = matrix(1:4,3,4))
[1] TRUE
[1] 30
```

Without knowing what the specifics were, I experimented with `sum` a bit and this is what it shows.

```
sum(matrix(1:4,3,4)[,NA])
[1] NA
sum(matrix(1:4,3,4)[,NULL])
[1] 0
sum(matrix(1:4,3,4)[,])
[1] 30
```

If we do not specify any index for the matrix, `sum` sums all its values.

From reading the blog and the little experiment, I think that your custom functions work in cases where the used function processes provided data and is able to operate with missing arguments. In case of subsetting a matrix, the behaviour with missing arguments for subsets is that the function performs an operation over the whole dataset.

Comment: Just FYI: `matrix(1:4,3,4)[,NA]` and `matrix(1:4,3,4)[,NULL]` sets the matrix to all `NA` and to `NULL` respectively. Hence the result of `sum`.

Comment: We could see what is happening by defining a function like `foo2 = function(mat, j) substitute(sum(mat[, j]))` and, then, use it `foo2(matrix(1:4, 3, 4))`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @nya answer:

You can avoid this behavior by inserting an `if`-statement inside the function, that assesses whether or a value for `j` has been supplied when calling the function. If no value is supplied, the function will throw an error:

```
foo <- function(mat, j){
   if(missing(j)){                # Check if argument for j has been supplied
       error("j is not inserted")
   } else{
       v <- sum(mat[,j])
       return(v)
     }
   }
```